# How to place extra text on canvas (not using HTML) beside chart?

Tags: canvas, chart.js

I'm using chart.js ver.2 to make different charts. There are some fixed places where you can place info, like in title and legend. But if I want to put some text in "unused areas" of the canvas it doesn't seem to work by just using standard self.Context.fillText calls after animation onComplete. Is writing a chart plugin the only way? If so, any help with that?

I have a function called on the onComplete event that among other things enables a print button. Since  the print function copies the canvas I need the info to be part of the canvas and not done as HTML.

Context is in self.Context. I just put in some lines for test:

```
self.Context.fillStyle = "blue";
self.Context.font = "bold 16px Arial";
self.Context.fillText("Tommy", 10, self.chart.canvas.height - 50);
```

...but nothing is shown. So it seems chart.js "owns" the canvas and I would need to extend chart.js functionality with a plugin for that.

[image: Pie]

There's a lot of white spice on this (test data) chart canvas and it would be nice to be able to use that for giving some more info to the users.

Is a chart.js plugin the only non-HTML way?
If so, any usable example to help me write one?

Comment: From what my googling has shown, I have concluded that the only way to do what I want is to extend the draw routine of chart.js. Since my display routine is generic and doesn't know from where I get the data I will need create an array with coordinates and text strings. The draw routine will then check if strings are non-empty and if so display them att given coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can create an Extend function for each of the different chart types (for instance you may want to place the text at different places depending on chart type), here's an example for a line chart:

```
            let myLineExtend = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
            Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.line.prototype, {
                draw: function () {
                    myLineExtend.apply(this, arguments);
                    self.Context.save();
                    self.Context.fillStyle = "#032f55";
                    var ctx = self.Context;
                    ctx.textAlign = "left";
                    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
                    ctx.font = "12px arial";
                    ctx.fillText("Random text", (self.chart.canvas.width * 1) / 10, (self.chart.canvas.height * 3) / 4);
                    self.Context.restore();
                }
            });
```